# Restrict submitters from wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, users

Is it possible, if a subscriber wants to enter wp-admin, that the page would be rdirectet to any page I want ?

If yes, please how :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, drop this code into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_244614_no_dashboard_for_subscriber' );
function wpse_244614_no_dashboard_for_subscriber() {

    $to = 'https://google.com/';

    $is_subscriber = current_user_can( 'subscriber' );
    $in_backend    = is_admin();
    $doing_ajax    = defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX;

    if ( $is_subscriber && $in_backend && ! $doing_ajax ) {
        wp_redirect( $to );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now whenever a subscriber tries to reach the backend, he will be redirected to Google, you can use the website homepage `home_url()` or whatever you want.